# Using a generic type of a subclass within it's abstract superclass?

Tags: java, generics, class, abstract-class

Within my code a have the following abstract superclass

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<Type extends A> {...}
```

and some child classes like

```
public class ChildClassA extends AbstractClass<GenericTypeA> {...}

public class ChildClassB extends AbstractClass<GenericTypeB> {...}
```

I'm searching for an elegant way how I can use the generic type of the child classes (GenericTypeA, GenericTypeB, ...) inside the abstract class in a generic way.

To solve this problem I currently defined the method

```
protected abstract Class<Type> getGenericTypeClass();
```

in my abstract class and implemented the method

```
@Override
protected Class<GenericType> getGenericTypeClass() {
    return GenericType.class;
}
```

in every child class.

Is it possible to get the generic type of the child classes in my abstract class without implementing this helper method?

BR,

Markus

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think its possible. I saw this was being used in the DAO patterns along with generics. e.g.
Consider classes:

```
public class A {}
public class B extends A {}
```

And your generic class:

```
  import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
  public abstract class Test<T extends A> {

     private Class<T> theType;

     public Test()  {
        theType = (Class<T>) (
               (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
              .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
     }

     // this method will always return the type that extends class "A"
     public Class<T> getTheType()   {
        return theType;
     }

     public void printType() {
        Class<T> clazz = getTheType();
        System.out.println(clazz);
     }
  }
```

You can have a class Test1 that extends Test with class B (it extends A)

```
  public class Test1 extends Test<B>  {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 t = new Test1();

        Class<B> clazz = t.getTheType();

        System.out.println(clazz); // will print 'class B'
        System.out.println(printType()); // will print 'class B'
     }
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand what the code in the constructor of Test really does, but it worked. Now I don't have to use the helper methods any longer. Thanks :-)

Comment: It uses reflection. First it gets the Generic superclass (java.lang.reflect.Type) of the class, in our case it will never be null and we know that it is a ParameterizedType, so we cast it and call the method getActualTypeArguents that returns an array of the actual type arguments e.g. B, of the type.

Comment: Be aware that creating either a `class Test2 extends Test1` or a `class TestFail<T> extends Test<T>` will break the above code.

Comment: @ILMTitan if someone is interested in code that can handle near all possible chains of inheritance you can check answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60299767/4378853

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question - `<Type>` *is* the generic type of the subclass, even when it's being expressed in the abstract class.  For example, if your abstract superclass defines a method:

```
public void augment(Type entity) {
   ...
}
```

and you instantiate a `ChildClassA`, you'll only be able to call `augment` with an instance of `GenericTypeA`.

Now if you want a class literal, then you'll need to provide the method as you indicated.  But if you just want the generic parameter, you don't need to do anything special.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really got your point. Type is extended by the the generic types of the sub classes. Therefore it is possible to cast the type of the sub class back to Type and to use it inside the abstract super class.

Comment: @Markus - Now *I* don't understand your second sentence, I don't think it makes sense.  You can't cast a type parameter in any sense; in the class definition(s) it's merely a placeholder pointing to the type you actually create an object with.  And the subclasses don't *extend* type, they provide a concrete bound for it.  So when the methods in `AbstractClass` are being invoked for an instance of `ChildClassA`, `type` **is** `GenericTypeA`.